# Increasing header height margin in rdlc

Tags: c#, export, report, rdlc, doc

In my rdlc file, I have header, content, and footer. What I'd like to do is to increase the top margin from the header. However, I am unable to do it.

I have tried the following:
**1.** Adjust the top margin in report properties. This adjusts the top margin from the content, *but not the header*. Also, **2.** Adjust the height of the header. No matter how much I increase the height, when the .doc file is generated, it remains the same size as before, which is very frustrating.

Is there any way I can set the height of the header conveniently (and without massive changes, such as inserting empty textboxes inside my header and such)? Many thanks...!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid but is clearly explained that the header height is NOT supported when you are rendering the report in Word format.

> Page headers and footers are rendered as header and footer regions in Word. If a report page number or an expression that indicates the total number of report pages appears in the page header or footer, they are translated to a Word field so that the accurate page number is displayed in the rendered report. **If the header or footer height is set in the report, Word cannot support this setting**.

[MSDN source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283105%28v=sql.105%29.aspx#ReportHeadersFooters)

And [here you can find](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/6d752bf2-a656-4807-b047-8148114feacd) a thread about it in the msdn forum