# how to set the height of header is auto increasing in rdlc

Tags: c#, sql-server, report, rdlc

I am using RDLC to create a report.

In header, there is Textbox which has dynamic content.

When the height of Textbox content exceeds header height, it was overlain because header height is static.

So how to set the height of header is auto increasing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016780/increasing-header-height-margin-in-rdlc

Comment: hi @Vaibs_Cool, my question is not same the question you comment. I just want the height of header is auto

Comment: Your question is exactly the same and the answer is that it isn't possible to increase the maximum height of the header. If you need the entire textbox to be displayed, you'll have to place it outside of the header and adjust the margins so it uses less white space at the top of your page.